# Center div but not inner divs

Tags: html, css, center

i have a code like this

```
    <center>
        <div id="inner_a"></div>
        <div id="inner_b"></div>
        <div id="inner_c"></div>
        <div id="inner_d"></div>
        <div id="inner_e"></div>
        <div id="inner_f"></div>
        <div id="inner_g"></div>
        <div id="inner_h"></div>
        <div id="inner_i"></div>
    </center>
```

this centers everything, but if there are free spaces in the last row, the inner div is located in the center and I want it to be located on the left

Comment: `<center>` tag is obsolete, you shouldn't be using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center
use CSS techniques instead

Comment: such as `margin: auto`, `display: flex; justify-content: center`, etc...